# Eliminate to be verb

Tags: verbs, american-english, sentence, be

How can I eliminate the weak "to be" verb (DOES) in the following sentence:

```
She does not assist in accomplishing...
```

Comment: The verb _be_ and the verb _does_ are both Auxiliary Verbs. They are not called "to be" verbs; they're called auxiliary verbs. And you can't get rid of it unless you get rid of the "not". Negatives require an auxiliary verb. So do questions. If there isn't one there already, we use _do_. So that's why you can't get rid of it. Why would you want to do that, anyway?

Comment: Perhaps, depending on whether a positive on negative emphasis is required, we could use *ever* or *never* --  *She **never** assists in accomplishing ...* -- *Has she **ever** assisted in ...*

Comment: I think a little more description of context is required, because all the answers change the meaning. The OP sentence is essentially neutral and "does not assist" could easily mean "She is unhelpful" or "She is a hindrance" as well as "She stands idle and watches". Because (as @JohnL says) auxiliary verbs are the way English works, removing them will always change the meaning. We need to know what meaning is intended in order to remove *does* in the right way.

Comment: This question is a request for writing advice (off-topic request for opinions). While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one is unlikely to help future readers. Writing advice is sometimes on topic at [writers.se]. General help learning better English is on topic at [ell.se].

Comment: To get rid of the 'not', look for an antonym of the verb (not that there is a good one for 'assist').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
She NEVER assists us in accomplishing...
```

Comment: She won't assist us in accomplishing...

Comment: You are right, I suppose. Why not update your question as well?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: formal writing should not include contractions according to my teacher, and also will not includes another "to be" verb (will)

Answer (score 1):

She lends no assistance in accomplishing . . .

Answer (score 1):

She assists not in accomplishing...

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but perhaps it's just not that great of an answer. Although you are rearranging the sentence to remove **doesn't**, the resulting sentence sounds a bit archaic.

Answer (score 1):

Her assistance, noticeable only by its absence, accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`Her assistance is entirely absent...`

--
Still contains a "to be" verb but feels stronger:

`Her assistance does not accomplish...`

Answer (score -1):

- We could observe the incompatibility between her and the ability assisting us in accomplishing ...
- We have encountered her inability to assist us in accomplishing ...
- We soon find that her inability to assist us in accomplishing ...
- They are frustrated by her inability to assist them in accomplishing ...
- We should find ways to deal with her inability to assist us in accomplishing ...
- I am sick and tired of her inability to assist us in accomplishing ...
- I don't want her as a member in the task force due to her inability to assist us in accomplishing ...

Answer (score -2):

She's not assistive in accomplishing... [All through his employment at Glorious Enterprises, Mr. Troy was appreciated for his assistive nature, marketing skills...](http://www.samplemessages.com/letters/job-recommendation-letter.html)